# How kill running procedure in cx_oracle?

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

I have very long time executable proc, and need close it. What is the best way to do this?? Using Oracle 19, cx_oracle 7.2.2. Connection started in SessionPool.

Found several ways, **throw ^C forcibly** and try

```
ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL 'SID, SERIAL[, @INST_ID][, SQL_ID]';
```

Comment: What about [Connection.cancel()](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html?highlight=cancel#Connection.cancel) ?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not explicitly use transactions, but only autocommit

Comment: The doc is poor (I'll fix it).  The call should kill long running SQL statements and PL/SQL calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you have either the cancel sql statement you pointed to, or the alter system kill session method. The first one will just cancel the current sql (if you specify the sql_id), and then the session continues (depending on how you handle errors in your code). The second method will kill your session, and your program will need to recapture a connection from the pool and try again.
Another comment, you better upgrade your cx_oracle to the newest oracledb provider. 7.2 is fairly old.